Requests webdriver loop
My code looks like this:
    def download_article_picture(self):
        """ Downloads the article picture if available based on an input url
        """
        for i in range(len(self._picture_link_list)):
            picture_url = self._picture_link_list[i]
            picture_filename = self._news_list["picture_filename"][i]
    
            output_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'output')
            output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, picture_filename)
            response = requests.get(picture_url)
            # Download
            if response.status_code:
                fp = open(output_path, 'wb')
                fp.write(response.content)
                fp.close()


I was having a lot of trouble with infinite loops, aka:
"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" from ssl.py: `super(SSLContext, SSLContext)

I tried using gevent to solve this problem, seen here
so I added:
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import requests

However, now I have the error:
self._ctx, value
AttributeError: 'SSLContext' object has no attribute '_ctx'

I have no ideia of what is happening.

This code doesn't have an infinite loop or recursion. Please post the relevant code.

Please show the complete traceback

I tried to create a shorter file in order to reproduce the error, but for some reason the error is gone!
So the code really had no issue, my hypothesis is that something on the imports was incorrect/unused, or I had another function that got removed in the process...
Anyway, thank you for the responses!!
